# mysql db connection with java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using type 4 driver for mysql. Code is given below. In every java file i'm creating db connection and closing at the end. For example

In abc.java

```
 Dbconnection db=null;
 Connection con=null;
 PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
public ActionForward execute(----)
  {
 try{
    db=new Dbconnection();//instantiating user defined Dbconnection class object
    con=db.getConnection();//creating connection object
    ...........
    Login_Check formBean=(Login_Check)form;//bean class object

    pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select type from user_registration where user_name=? and password=? and user_status=?");
    //form parameter values
    pstmt.setString(1,formBean.getUname().trim());
    pstmt.setString(2,formBean.getPassword().trim());
    pstmt.setString(3,"Active");//user status should be active

    ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            ................
            db.releasePreparedStatement(pstmt);
            db.releaseConnection(con);

            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);//redirecting to success page
        }
        else
        {
            ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
            errors.add("both", new ActionMessage("errors.both.wrong"));//if both user name and password is incorrect, gives an error message
            saveErrors(request,errors);

            //closing connection and prepareStatement objects
            db.releasePreparedStatement(pstmt);
            db.releaseConnection(con);

            return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);//redirecting to failure page
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);//redirecting to failure page
  }
```

Like that in every java file I'm following the same way..

In Dbconnection.java file

```
public class Dbconnection
{
    Connection con=null;
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    String USER = "abc";//db user name
    String PASS = "abc";//db password
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

     public synchronized Connection getConnection()
     {
       try
       {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//loading mysql driver 
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);//connecting to mysql
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
         return con;
      }

      public void releaseConnection(Connection conn)//releasing Connection
      {
         if(conn!=null)
          {
             try
              {
                 conn.close();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
    }

    public void releasePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement stmt)//closing PreparedStatement object
    {
       if(stmt!=null)
       {
         try
         {
              stmt.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
  }
}
```

But the problem is sometimes I'm getting a success message. But some times I'm getting a failure message. In server i'm getting error

```
The operation is not allowed after ResultSet is closed
```

The above problem is occurs only while multiple users are accessing the same file (ex abc.java).

Comment: Try to close the `preparedStatement` before the `connection`, also you should include more code because the ResultSet referenced in your exception does not appear in the code you provided...

Comment: more code means? Is it the correct way like creating and closing a connection.

Comment: Add the missing code in abc.java

Comment: I've added the some missing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

1) Close the PreparedStatement and Connection in a `finally` block, so if the code get an `exception` your code will properly close the resources, otherwise you could have a memory leak.

2) if in your code you use a `ResultSet` like

```
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
......
```

Then you should close it before reusing it again...

3) Is your method in `abc.java` static?

I will do something like this, move the `close` method in the `finally` block, to prevent memory leak in case of exception

```
public ActionForward execute(----) {
    Dbconnection db=null;
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        db=new Dbconnection();//instantiating user defined Dbconnection class object
        con=db.getConnection();//creating connection object

        // some code
        Login_Check formBean = (Login_Check) form;//bean class object

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select type from user_registration where user_name=? and password=? and user_status=?");
        //form parameter values
        pstmt.setString(1, formBean.getUname().trim());
        pstmt.setString(2, formBean.getPassword().trim());
        pstmt.setString(3, "Active"); //user status should be active

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            /* some code */
            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);//redirecting to success page
        }
        else
        {
            ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
            errors.add("both", new ActionMessage("errors.both.wrong"));//if both user name and password is incorrect, gives an error message
            saveErrors(request,errors);
            return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);//redirecting to failure page
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        db.releaseResultSet(rs);
        db.releasePreparedStatement(pstmt);
        db.releaseConnection(con);
    }

    return mapping.findForward(FAILURE);//redirecting to failure page
  }
```

You obviously need to add the new `releaseResultSet` method in Dbconnection to release the set...

Comment: hi@Marcx, I've updated some code. Can you please tell me the correct way to write.

Comment: If condition is true then it will redirecting to success page. Does this code will close db connection.

Comment: yes it will!!! the finally block is ALWAYS executed, also if there is a `return` in the `try/catch`...

Comment: is it mandatory to close statement obj. Shall I write a single line to close a connection without close a statement. like db.releaseConnection(con);

Comment: You need to close everything you have opened, otherwise you can occur in memory leaks... so you need to close `ResultSet` `PreparedStatement` and then `Connection`...